# How can I debug a cherrypy application using pyscripter?

Tags: python, cherrypy, pyscripter

Been looking around a bit and I can't seem to find any help on setting up debugging within pyscripter for cherrypy.  I have found [django](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/wiki/FAQ#How_can_I_debug_Django_applications?), but not cherrypy.

I'm using the remote engine, but the breakpoints aren't catching.

Comment: I debug with `pdb`, or preferably with `ipdb`. What do you expect which pdb/ipdb doesn't provide?

Comment: Didn't know about pdb - that worked great.  If you put it as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you can debug with `pdb`, or preferably with `ipdb` (which provides some extra features like tab completions). `pdb` is the standard( & builtin, as opposed to `ipdb`) python debugger.